# React Native font size

Tags: react-native, styles

I have mockup in photoshop, resolution of mockup is 1242x2208 and font size 50px.

How can I recalculate for right font size for device?

For example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHxmu.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubtly those are 50px, maybe 50dp, but try as following.

Import this:

```
import { PixelRatio } from 'react-native'
```

And try using this:

```
PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(200)
```

Also, have a look at that [PixelRatio](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html).